# Windows security: default owner configurable?

Tags: windows, access-control-list

The "[How owners are assigned and set](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961992.aspx)" Technet article is stating:

> By default, a new object's owner is the security principal identified as the default owner in the access token attached to the creating process. When an object is created, the SID stored in the access token's Owner field is copied to the security descriptor's Owner field. The default owner is normally an individual—the user who is currently logged on. The only exceptions occur when the user is a member of either the Administrators group or the Domain Admins group. In both cases, the Owner field in the user's access token contains the SID for the group, not the SID for the individual user account. The assumption is that administrative accounts are used only to administer the system and not for any individual purpose. As a result, objects created by one administrator can be managed by other administrators in the same group.

When seeing this, I wondered if the default owner is configurable. The access token is being built upon logon, so the `default owner` attribute would be dynamically generated either by a set of rules or by reading and transferring an AD/SAM attribute. If it is the latter, it would technically be possible to set the `default owner` to any arbitrary SID.

The (somewhat related) [MSDN article on understanding security descriptor defaulting rules](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/openspecification/archive/2009/08/28/understanding-security-descriptor-defaulting-rules-for-active-directory-objects.aspx)  is referring to the AD Technical Specification section 7.1.3 for details, where I hoped to find the answer, but I am unable to find the correct section as the [MS-ADTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223122.aspx) seem to have undergone a major rewrite since.

Anyone who can shed some light on this?